# Converting control signals to byte ascii hex code in golang

Tags: go, websocket, ascii, gorilla

I am trying to capture signals like ctrl+c, ctrl+z, ctrl+\ in golang and write its equivalent hex code to websocket. I am doing something like below.

```
func (c *poc) writePump() {
    var b = make([]byte, 1)
    d := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(d, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTSTP, syscall.SIGQUIT)

    for {
        os.Stdin.Read(b)
        err = c.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, b)

        go func() {
            for {
                s := <-d
                err = cli.sendControlSignalToWebsockets(s)
            }
        }()

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to send UTF8 char: %s", err)
        }
    }
}

func (c *poc) sendControlSignalToWebsockets(s os.Signal) error {
    var err error

    switch s {
    case syscall.SIGINT:
        err = c.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte{'\003'})
    case syscall.SIGTSTP:
        err = c.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte{'\x1a'})
    case syscall.SIGQUIT:
        err = c.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte{'\x1c'})
    }

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Instead I want to do something like, capturing all signals and instead of hardcoding each signals equivalent to it's hexcode, convert signal to hexcode.

```
func (c *poc) writePump() {
    var b = make([]byte, 1)
    d := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(d)

    for {
        os.Stdin.Read(b)
        err = c.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, b)

        go func() {
            for {
                s := <-d
                //???? do some conversions and write it to websocket
            }
        }()

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to send UTF8 char: %s", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Curious to know if anyone has any idea. Thanks!

Comment: How did you land on those hex codes in the first place? There isn't an "equivalent hex code" for a process signal.

Comment: You could write the signal codes directly as bytes, but that doesn't make much sense. It looks like you are doing whatever it is you consider to be proper "conversion" of the signals to byte values.

Comment: The hex codes are defined by the UNIX terminal facility.  It's possible to use the system terminal library to  detect the terminal info, query the termcap db, and get at them, but that is likely more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: (are you making potentially bad assumptions about the listening client, perhaps, in light of this?)

Comment: http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html#EOL hex codes are here

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers from? syscall.Signal values are just ints.

Comment: Are you confusing control characters/sequences and signals?

Comment: @kittu -  Even in the guide you just posted - which is not complete - do you see how different systems/terms sometimes map character code differently?

Comment: From my previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877342/how-to-capture-os-signals-like-ctrlc-and-send-them-through-gorilla-websocket-in/48877740#48877740 . I found that we can capture ctrl+c signal and write its equivalent to websockets. Is it not possible to capture all signals and write it's equivalent ?

Comment: @BadZen - here is the correct link - http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html#cntrl . I am currently focussing on linux/unix

Comment: Let me put it this way:   a user's dotfile or the system dotfiles could change that character with `stty` and that would break your entire scheme.   The keycodes are not mapped to signals in a neat way like you think.  What are you doing on the other side that you think you need the keycode for?   (It's probably buggy-by-design in light of what I've just told you...)

Comment: If OTOH you aren't using the keycode in a terminal / process input at all, just use the signal number instead as @JimB suggested  No "conversion" nec'y and your code simplifies.

Comment: @JimB can you please explain what do you mean by write signal codes directly as bytes?

Comment: @kittu: signals are just a integer value, and can all be expressed as a single byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to communicate a signal over a websocket. And thus you need a way to encode it won't get confused with other characters so using the unprintable ascii characters is a reasonable move.

Since there is no convention for mapping `syscall` signals into a `byte`, you can't just import it - but good news! - you get to create your own!

Create a  `map[syscall.Signal]byte` or `map[os.Signal]byte` and do the translation from there:

```
// Create a mapping between syscalls and bytes
var syscallByteMap = map[syscall.Signal]byte{
  syscall.SIGINT: '\003',
  ...more here...
}

...truncated...

        go func() {
        for {
            s := <-d
            // Look up the signal in the map
            b, ok := syscallByteMap[s]
            if ok {
                err = c.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte{b})
            } else {
                err = nil
            }

        }
    }()
```

Comment: I'd also note that POSIX did not cover all the signals used (refer to the `signal(7)` manual page for more info—that is, run `man 7 signal). Hence, instead of trying to "hex-encode" signals somehow I'd probably map them onto something human-readable (like strings) if possible.